# Formula or relation for forcing spring movement over a certain time (as the image shows)

Tags: classical-mechanics

i have explained my objectives in the image
[image]

the fact is i'm planning to use such motion in programming
but i have some serious trouble over controling the time that this motion finishes!
what i'm trying to say is, i need a constant motion that finishes in 2 second and if it needs to be finished in 1 second i must be able to change all variables so the motion happens faster , but the same, so it finishes in 1 second
i hope my explanation isn't very unclear.
(i have only studied classical physics a long time ago, so please be through while explaining)
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to described damped simple harmonic motion? What is the force of friction? Are you assuming that the spring can be stretched to 100 m length, and that its neutral position is at the "target position"? Currently your question is extremely unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: please check the answer one again i made some changes , and yes i am indeed trying to describe damped simple harmonic motion (i didn't know it was called that !), consider friction and all other parameters whatever you like as long as it produces a fairly normal , home like spring movement , as i said in the question i just need everything to be under my control in a time based equation(which i give the time and a simple motion is played in that time and all other variables are calculated so it finishes in that time.

Comment: Someone did this already http://www.ncsu.edu/per/Articles/MarchewkaAbbott&Beichner.pdf

Comment: @Rol i'm studying the article hopefully it helps

Comment: Please note that "finite number of times that it crosses zero" is not a realistic constraint: if you assume damped simple harmonic motion you get either no zero crossing (heavy damping), exactly one crossing (critical damping), or "infinitely many" (light damping). The best you can hope for is that the amplitude becomes "small enough not to matter" after a certain number of crossings. So once again - can you be more explicit in your requirements? It's already much better than it was initially...

Answer (score 1):

The general equation is $$x(t) = x_0+ {\bf e}^{-\beta t} \left( A \sin \omega t + B \cos \omega t\right)$$

where the constants $A$ and $B$ depend on the initial conditions, and $\beta$ and $\omega$ on the mechanical properties of the system.

Read http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html for more information

For example if the initial conditions are $x(0)=x_0+\delta$ and $\dot{x}(0)=0$, then $B=\delta$ and $A=\frac{\beta \delta}{\omega}$

If the spring stiffness is $k$, the damping is $d$ and the mass is $m$ then the equation of motion is

$$ m \ddot{x} + d \dot{x} + k (x-x_0) = 0 $$

Using the general solution one arrives at $\beta = \frac{d}{2 m}$ and $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}-\beta^2}$

Comment: Good start. I took the liberty of writing another answer based in part off this one but with more details.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to be read in conjunction with @ja72's answer.

Assuming that you are modeling damped simple harmonic motion, where the drag force is proportional to the velocity, you can control 3 variables: the spring constant $k$, the mass $m$ and the coefficient of damping $\mu$ (where force of drag $F = \mu v$).

This allows you to set the time for the mass to return to zero for the first time (approximately given by $T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$) and control the "envelope" of the damping by changing $\mu$. For a mass starting at rest, and lightly damped motion (otherwise you will only get a single zero-crossing) the equation of motion is

$$x(t) = A e^{-\mu t/2m}\cos(\omega t)$$

where $\omega = \sqrt{k/m-\mu^2/4m^2}$

As you can see, zero crossings will keep happening "indefinitely" as the motion never truly stops (according to this equation).

You have two options: 1) for the most rapid "approach to zero" you want to use "critically damped motion" - when $k/m = \mu^2/4m^2$ the equation actually changes, and you get the faster possible return to equilibrium. This is the kind of damping that is used in analog voltmeters etc - where you want the needle to settle quickly "to the right value". 2) for light damping (which you seem to want since you specified you wanted multiple zero crossings) the best you can do is state the minimum amplitude that you consider "stationary". Then you solve the amplitude envelope - in other words, if you want amplitude reduced to 1% of the initial value after 5 zero crossings, you would solve

$$e^{-mu t/2m} = 0.01$$
with
$$t = \frac52 T = 5 \pi \sqrt{m/k}$$

This gives the relationship between $\mu$ and $m$; if you further want this to happen within a certain time, you have the relationship between $m$ and $k$.

This leaves you with one parameter to choose freely, and the other two follow. That makes sense, of course. The same problem could be solved with a mass of 1 kg or 2 kg (if you just imagine the mass of 2 kg to be two identical masses on identical springs, you see that as long as mass and spring constant scale, the choice of value doesn't actually matter).